# ::before selector coming on the top of the image container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to embbed the ::before selector of the image container behind the image but it is
coming on the top on the image ,I want that ::before container comes according to the postion
I Have mentioned in the coding

```
    **html**

       <div class='main'>
        <img src="imgg.png">
        </div>

  **css**

    .main{
      height:150px;
      width:150px;
      margin:0 auto;
      position:relative;
      margin-top:1rem;
      
    }
    img{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      background-size:cover;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      border-radius:50%;
      
    }
    .main::before{
      display:block;
      content:"";
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      position:absoulte;
      top:-1rem;
      right:-1rem;
      background-color:red;
      border-radius:50%;
     
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure of what you trying to achieve, if it's to position the :before behind your image, you can try to add `z-index: -1` to your :before. But to try something more accurate, I'll need a reproducible example

Comment: When I apply positon:relative on the img it fits according to what I want but the logic is not clear to me how relative working here....

Comment: I've explained the reason in my answer, please also remove the duplicate code in your css (both position and top/left are duplicated, so only the latest value is considered)

Answer (score -1):

The `position: absolute` property aligns the DOM element based on the closest positioned ancestor (positioned = not with the default position property).

This is why the code works when you set `position: relative` to the img tag. Without it, it would look further up the DOM tree, and if it doesn't find any positioned element, it will align the object relative to the browser window.

Here you can find some more informations about positioned layout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position